# Breaking a string on dates

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following script I have altered to split a large string into sentances.  However I am having issues getting it to also break on dates.

Original working code:

```
$re = '/# Split sentences on whitespace between them.
(?<=                # Begin positive lookbehind.
  [.!?:]             # Either an end of sentence punct,
| [.!?:][\'"]
| [\r\t\n]              # or end of sentence punct and quote.
)                   # End positive lookbehind.
(?<!                # Begin negative lookbehind.
  Mr\.              # Skip either "Mr."
| Mrs\.             # or "Mrs.",    
| Ms\.              # or "Ms.",
| Jr\.              # or "Jr.",
| Dr\.              # or "Dr.",
| Prof\.            # or "Prof.",
| U\.S\.A\.
| Sr\.              # or "Sr.",
| T\.V\.A\.         # or "T.V.A.",
| a\.m\.            # or "a.m.",
| p\.m\.            # or "p.m.",
| â€¢\.
| :\.
| •\.

                    # or... (you get the idea).
)                   # End negative lookbehind.
\s+                 # Split on whitespace between sentences.

/ix';

$sentences = preg_split($re, $block_o_text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sentences); ++$i) {
```

I have added [0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9], but it doesn't seem to be having the desired effect.  What am I missing?  Here Is my updated code below:

```
$re = '/# Split sentences on whitespace between them.
(?<=                # Begin positive lookbehind.
  [.!?:]             # Either an end of sentence punct,
| [.!?:][\'"]
| [\r\t\n]          # or end of sentence punct and quote.
| [0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9] # or on a date
)                   # End positive lookbehind.
(?<!                # Begin negative lookbehind.
  Mr\.              # Skip either "Mr."
| Mrs\.             # or "Mrs.",    
| Ms\.              # or "Ms.",
| Jr\.              # or "Jr.",
| Dr\.              # or "Dr.",
| Prof\.            # or "Prof.",
| U\.S\.A\.
| Sr\.              # or "Sr.",
| T\.V\.A\.         # or "T.V.A.",
| a\.m\.            # or "a.m.",
| p\.m\.            # or "p.m.",
| â€¢\.
| :\.
| •\.

                    # or... (you get the idea).
)                   # End negative lookbehind.
\s+                 # Split on whitespace between sentences.

/ix';
```

Comment: You probably would be better served building a parser than trying to build some extremely complicated regex.

Answer (score 1):

Dates do not have only single digits especially in the year. You need to account for that. You also need to escape the `/` since that is your regex delimiter.

```
[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}
```